# How to show a message randomly between the main content in rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, twitter

I have a rails app where users can Sign Up/Sign In and post stories, follow other authors, what I want to achieve is how to put some content like `Authors to follow` in between of the main content while the user is scrolling (Like what Twitter does with `Who to follow`.

[image]

with react I have created a User_Follow_suggestion_container:

```
<%= react_component('FollowSuggestionsContainer') %>
```

It works fine, now I want to know, where to place it, so it can come randomly or after scrolling down to 10 or 15 posts.

**my dashboard.html.erb**

```
<div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-1 dashboard-main-content">
  <% unless @dashboard.top_stories? %>
    <% if user_signed_in? && current_page?('/') %>
      <div data-animation="fadeInUp-fadeOutDown">
        <%= render 'shared/inline_editor' %>
      </div>
    <% end %>
    <div class="posts-wrapper" data-behavior="endless-scroll" data-animation="fadeInUp-fadeOutDown">
      <%= render @dashboard.posts %>
    </div>
  <% else %>
    <div class="posts-wrapper" data-animation="fadeInUp-fadeOutDown">
      <%= render 'posts/top_stories', posts: @dashboard.posts %>
    </div>
  <% end %>
  <% unless @dashboard.top_stories? %>
    <div class="center">
      <%= will_paginate @dashboard.posts %>
    </div>
  <% end %>
</div>

<%= react_component('FollowSuggestionsContainer') %>
```